# R: issue with converting factor to numeric

Tags: r, matrix, numeric, type-conversion

I am playing around with a data set that I got from this website: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

I want to use a package that requires the matrix to be a numeric one so I used data.matrix to convert the data frame into a numeric matrix.

Here is my first question: is there a way to tell which number corresponds to which factor? This is easy just by looking at the data in the case with the data set given by this website, but how would we achieve this when we have hundreds of factors?

My second question deals with the following code:

```
as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
```

I saw on a different post that this is the most efficient way of converting a factor into a numeric value. However, using this command on one of the columns in the data set gives me this result:

```
as.numeric(levels(ml$prog))[ml$prog]
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [64] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[127] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[190] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

On the other hand, if I just use the following code:

```
as.numeric(ml$prog)
  [1] 3 1 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 1 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 1 3 2 2 3 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 1 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 3 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 3 2 3
 [96] 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
[191] 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2
```

It seems to return the result I expected.

Just to give more background information, the column `ml$prog` has three levels of factors: `"academic", "general", and "vocation"`.

Comment: The number should reflect the order of the levels.  If your levels are 'academic', 'general', 'vocation' then these should be 1,2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your mixup is due to the fact that the encoded vector is not numeric but character.  If you need a number then your `as.numeric(ml$prog)` is the right answer.  If you want to access the encoded vector then `as.character(levels(ml$prog))[ml$prog]`

Comment: For the second of those, you could just do `as.character(ml$prog)`